# What is the point of Python's importlib?

Tags: python, import, python-import

Is this "convenience wrapper": https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html just providing another way of writing:

```
import path.to.my.module
```

Is there something is does that you can't do with a normal import statement?

Answer (score 10):

It allows you to import modules which you do not know the name at coding time.

For instance when my application starts, I walk through a directory structure and load the modules as I discover them.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.7, `importlib` isn't *super* useful.  In fact, its only feature is the `import_module` function, which enables you to import a module from a string name:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.import_module('sys')
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> importlib.import_module('sys').version
'2.7.8 (default, Jul  2 2014, 19:50:44) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'
>>>
```

Note that you could do the same with the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) built-in, but using `import_module` is generally preferred.

In Python versions 3.1 and greater however, the purpose of `importlib` has been expanded.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#introduction):

> The purpose of the `importlib` package is two-fold. One is to provide an
>   implementation of the import statement (and thus, by extension, the
>   `__import__()` function) in Python source code. This provides an implementation of `import` which is portable to any Python interpreter.
>   This also provides a reference implementation which is easier to
>   comprehend than one implemented in a programming language other than
>   Python.
>
> Two, the components to implement import are exposed in this package,
>   making it easier for users to create their own custom objects (known
>   generically as an importer) to participate in the import process.
>   Details on custom importers can be found in [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302).

Summarized, `importlib` now allows you to access the internals of Python's import-statement, build custom finders, loaders, and importers, setup import hooks, and much more.

In fact, as of version 3.3, `importlib` holds the implementation of the import-statement itself.  You can read about this on the What's New in Python 3.3 page under [Using `importlib` as the Implementation of Import](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#using-importlib-as-the-implementation-of-import).

Also, `importlib` will be replacing older modules related to importing in future versions of Python. For example, the old [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) module was deprecated in version 3.4 in favor of `importlib`.

With all of this in mind, I guess it's safe to say that `importlib` is pretty important in modern Python. ;)

Comment: Please also note: starting from Python 3.3 `import` statement itself is implemented by `importlib` package, not by very complex C code.