# import vs __import__( ) vs importlib.import_module( )?

Tags: python, python-import

I noticed Flask was using Werkzeug to `__import__` a module, and I was a little confused. I went and checked out the docs on it and saw that it seems to give you more control somehow in terms of where it looks for the module, but I'm not sure *exactly* how and I have zero idea how it's different from `importlib.import_module`.

The odd thing in the Werkzeug example is that it just says `__import__(import_name)`, so I don't see how that's any different from just using the `import` statement, since it's ignoring the optional extra parameters.

Can anyone explain? I looked at other people having asked similar questions on SO previously but they weren't very clearly phrased questions and the answers didn't address this at all.

Comment: Use `__import__` where `you want to import a module whose name is only known at runtime`. Other than this... as you said this gives your more power compared to import

Comment: If memory serves correctly there is a David Beasely video on import, within the video he mentions that WerkZeug overloaded import for some reason.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) is a low-level hook function that's used to import modules; it can be used to import a module *dynamically* by giving the module name to import as a variable, something the `import` statement won't let you do.

[`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) is a wrapper around that hook<sup>*</sup> to produce a nice API for the functionality; it is a very recent addition to Python 2, and has been more fleshed out in Python 3. Codebases that use `__import__` generally do so because they want to remain compatible with older Python 2 releases, e.g. anything before Python 2.7.

One side-effect of using `__import__` can be that it returns the imported module and doesn't add anything to the namespace; you can import with it without having then to delete the new name if you didn't want that new name; using `import somename` will add `somename` to your namespace, but `__import__('somename')` instead returns the imported module, which you can then ignore. Werkzeug uses the hook for that reason in one location.

All other uses are to do with dynamic imports. Werkzeug supports Python 2.6 still so cannot use `importlib`.

---

<sup>*</sup> `importlib` is a Pure-Python implementation, and `import_module()` will use that implementation, whist `__import__` will use a C-optimised version. Both versions call back to `importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load()` so the difference is mostly academic.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "you can import with it without having then to delete the new name if you didn't want that new name." If you have a minute could you maybe flesh that out as if you were talking to a toddler?

Comment: @Aerovistae: updated that a little; `import sys` adds the name `sys` to your namespace (bound to the module), `__import__('sys')` returns the `sys` module object to the caller, which is then free to ignore that object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters By namespace do you mean `sys.modules`?

Comment: @NeoWang: by namespace I mean the globals of a module. These are stored as a dictionary on the `module` instance, which in turn is stored in `sys.modules`.

Comment: (Modified link in this comment) Does this answer requires modification? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307159/1317018) (specifically [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#using-importlib-as-the-implementation-of-import)), `__import__()` is not `importlib.__import__` and `import` statement is not implemented by `importlib`, that is, I guess `import` statement is now `importlib.import_module()`, right?

Comment: @Mahesha999: `import` is still using `__import__`, see [`import_name()` in the Python evaluation loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/ceval.c#L5199-L5237) (which the `IMPORT_NAME` bytecode calls). The [`__import__()` built-in](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/bltinmodule.c#L227-L257) calls the [`PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/import.c#L1480-L1645), which is a C port of the `importlib._bootstrap.__import__()` and its dependencies.

Comment: @Mahesha999: technically speaking, `importlib.import_module()` goes straight to `importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import()`, which is one of the helper functions that `importlib.__import__` uses, and which the C implementation has optimised; both codepaths end up calling `importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load()` though. *At no point does `import` use `importlib.import_module()`*.

Comment: Thats some more implementational facts and makes things more confusing. However, now I am trying to guess what all things I should keep in mind while deciding what I should be using: `import`, `__import__` and `importlib.__import__`. For example, now I am trying to write a code which will take a string of multiple py files (stored in database, instead of file system, for security reasons, uploaded by user from browser), create module from them and properly handle import in them. Or in any other scenario, what to prefer when: `import` statement, `__import__` or `importlib.__import__`.

Comment: @Mahesha999: To dynamically produce a module from source code stored in a string, you don't need to look at `__import__` at all. Create an empty module instance with `module = imporlib.util.module_from_spec(importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(module_name, None, origin='<string>'))`, store the module with `sys.modules[module_name] = module`, then use `exec(sourcecode, module.__dict__)` to execute your source code. And don't ever execute user-supplied code, that is extremely insecure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the issue was that what if that module itself have `import module1`, where `module1` is also a user supplied module (we have already considered security stuff)? So, I guess I had to override `__import__`, right? I have done `module=types.ModuleType(__name__)` instead of `module = imporlib.util.module_from_spec(...)` inside overrided `__import__`, is that ok?

Comment: @Mahesha999: No, then you are going too low level. Add a custom [`MetaPathFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder) to [`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path), and Python will ask it how to load your modules (Python asks each object in `sys.meta_path` in order for a `find_spec()` result until a result is found). This lets you specify a custom loader, so you can load your module from a database.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/import.html#replacing-the-standard-import-system), found these statements: *If it is acceptable to only alter the behaviour of import statements without affecting other APIs that access the import system, then replacing the builtin `__import__()` function may be sufficient. This technique may also be employed at the module level to only alter the behaviour of import statements within that module.* Does that suggest overriding `__import__` is suited for my scenario of dynamically creating and importing modules from source string?

Comment: @Mahesha999: this is really all getting way too long. If you feel your use case is better served by setting `builtins.__import__` to your own hook (or by setting it locally for a module executed with `exec`, like `namespace = {'__import__': your_hook}` then exec(sourcecode, namespace)`) then use that. I don't know your exact use case (nor are the comments a place for such a discussion).

Comment: yeah I know this is getting too long...very sorry and super thanks for pointing me to meta path stuff...will explore more myself and prepare question if I get stuck anywhere...thanks again!!!

Comment: is there a way to use __import__(modulename) to not only return the module but also import it?
I want a dual-solution, instead of having a place where I can check the module exists in the system and then load it into the namespace.

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška: `__import__(modulename)` *does* import it, if not already imported. Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am confused - I am running a loop on a list of module names and using __import__(next(module_str_names)) inside the loop, but if I do not declare the module name in an e.x. 'import csv' after, outside of the loop - I get a NameError, which tells me no module was imported, they were only checked. :/

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška: the issue is that you never assign the object returned by `__import__` to a name. If your code is relying on the the `csv` module being imported under the name `csv`, then **just use `import csv`**. Why use dynamic imports when the *rest* of your code is not dynamic? If you do need to import modules dynamically, use a dictionary or list to store the imported modules. Also see [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164)

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška: The `import` statement is a binding action, just like name assignment is. So `import csv` is equivalent to `csv = __import__('csv')`, while `import csv as foo` is equivalent to `foo = __import__('csv')`, `from csv import reader` is equivalent to `reader = __import__('csv').reader`, etc. You are not assigning to names in your loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my point is to check for their existence in the system as dependencies. If I assign the __import__(modulename) to like 'module = __import__(modulename)' and in the same loop do: 'import module' then I get a different problem of an infinite loop: 'csv is not present in the system. Installing with pip...
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for csv

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška: `csv` is a [**standard library module**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and doesn't need installing. Or testing for. It is always there if Python is installed. Your code should not be responsible for testing dependencies, your installer should be. If you have optional dependencies, just use `try: import modulename`, `except ImportError: <handle missing module>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210222/discussion-between-vaidotas-ivoska-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 9):

> `__import__(import_name)`, so I don't see how that's any different from
>   just using the import statement

Both `__import__()` and importlib.import_module() allow you to import a module when you have the module name as a string.  You cannot write:

```
x = 're'
import x
```

or you'll get:

```
 File "1.py", line 3, in <module>
 import x ImportError: No module named x
```