# How to trigger a late import of another module only when a certain object is needed from my module?

Tags: python, python-import

#### The Situation

I want to have a module that roughly works like the following:

```
# my_module.py

my_number = 17

from other_module import foo
my_object = foo(23)
```

However, there is a problem: Installing `other_module` causes problems for some users and is only required for those who want to use `my_object` – which in turn is only a small fraction of users. I want to spare those users who do not need `my_object` from installing `other_module`.

I therefore want the import of `other_module` to happen only if `my_object` is imported from `my_module`. With other words, the user should be able to run the following without having installed `other_module`:

```
from my_module import my_number
```

#### My best solution so far

I could provide `my_object` via a function that contains the import:

```
# in my_module.py

def get_my_object():
    from other_module import foo
    my_object = foo(23)
    return my_object
```

The user would then have to do something like:

```
from my_module import get_my_object
my_object = get_my_object()
```

#### Question

Is there a better way to conditionally trigger the import of `other_module`? I am mostly interested in keeping things as simple as possible for the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach A – clean solution

Create a new separate module and have the user import the object from the other module. For example

```
from my_module import my_number # regular use
from my_module.extras import my_object # for a small part of the user base
```

This means in your code you create a module folder `my_module` with an `__init__.py` where you import the usual stuff and don't import the `extras` submodule.

If you don't want to put `extras` in `my_module` (simpler), just create `my_object` in an individual `extras.py` module.

#### Approach B – signals bad architecture 99% of times

You can use `importlib.import_module` to dynamically import a module inside `get_my_object` without polluting the global space and that is **cleaner than an import inside a function which creates side effects such as overriding your global variable with that import name** (see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231738/import-vs-import-vs-importlib-import-module)), however this is *usually* a sign of bad coding patterns on other part of the code.

#### Approach C – simple and effective

I usually tend to favour this simple pattern when there are users that might not have a library, as Python 3 discourages imports that are not at top level:

```
try:
    import other_module
    _HAS_OTHER_MODULE_ = True
except:
    _HAS_OTHER_MODULE_ = False


def get_my_object():
    assert _HAS_OTHER_MODULE_, "Please install other module"
    return other_module.foo(23)
```

Comment: I am accepting this for Approach A, which I favour due to working in Python 3.6 and lower (which I want to support for a few years).

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the `get_my_object()` approach, but as of Python 3.7, what you ask is possible by defining a [module-level `__getattr__` function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/):

```
# my_module.py

my_number = 17

def __getattr__(name):
    if name != 'my_object':
        raise AttributeError
    global my_object
    from other_module import foo
    my_object = foo(23)
    return my_object
```

This will attempt to import `other_module` and call `foo` only once `my_object` is accessed. A few caveats:

- It will **not** trigger for attempts to access `my_object` by global variable lookup within `my_module`. It will only trigger on `my_module.my_object` attribute access, or a `from my_module import my_object` import (which performs attribute access under the hood).
- If you forget to assign to the global `my_object` name in `__getattr__`, `my_object` will be recomputed on every access.
- Module-level `__getattr__` does nothing before Python 3.7, so you may want to perform a version check and do something else for Python 3.6 and below:

  ```
  import sys
  if sys.version_info >= (3, 7):
      def __getattr__(name):
          ...
  else:
      # Do something appropriate. Maybe raise an error. Maybe unconditionally
      # import other_module and compute my_object up front.
  ```

Comment: Apparently I've been a little bit late answering with nearly the same answer, but it was because I was trying out that exact solution and unfortunately I couldn't get it to work with 3.7.2 for some reason.

Comment: That’s weirdly cool, thanks. The only downside is that it only works in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common hack to be done:

```
import sys

class MockModule:
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.module = module

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'dependency_required_var':
            try:
                import foo
                return self.module.dependency_required_var
            except ImportError:
                raise Exception('foo library is required to use dependency_required_var')
        else:
            return getattr(self.module, attr)


MockModule.__name__ = __name__
sys.modules[__name__] = MockModule(sys.modules[__name__])

dependency_required_var = 0
```

With [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/), we can simply do (we should be able to but I couldn't get it to work) the following in Python 3.7 and higher:

```
def __getattr__(attr):
    if attr == 'dependency_required_var':
        try:
            import foo
            return dependency_required_var
        except ImportError:
            raise Exception('foo library is required to use dependency_required_var')
    else:
        return globals()[attr]
```

The PEP seems to be accepted, but the relevant pull request from the PEP seems to be closed, I'm actually not sure if it has been implemented or not.